# adding RealmSwift to Cocoa Touch Framework: missing required modules

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I try to include RealmSwift into a Cocoa Touch Framework: I dragged RealmSwift.framework into my Xcode project and added it to "Linked Framwork and Libraries".

I also added `$(PROJECT_DIR)/MyProject/RealmSwift.framework/Frameworks` to the `Framework Search Paths` but I still get the error:

> Missing required modules: Realm.Private, Realm

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Per [Realm's documentation on using Realm Swift's prebuilt dynamic frameworks](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#dynamic-install), you need to ensure that both `Realm.framework` and `RealmSwift.framework` are added to your Xcode project, can be found on the framework search path, and are configured to be linked by the targets that use Realm Swift. It's not necessary for `RealmSwift.framework/Frameworks` to be on the framework search path, only the directory *containing* `RealmSwift.framework`.

Comment: thanks - but if I do that, my cocoa touch framework does compile successfully, but if I use it in an iOS project I get `ld: framework not found Realm for architecture x86_64`

Comment: A linker error like that indicates that Realm.framework is not present on the framework search path for the target that's being built.

Comment: but do I have to set that on the app using my framework or on my framework itself?

Comment: Whichever target is giving you that linker error is the one that needs to have its framework search path adjusted.